# View com 2 model dentro de uma ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Objetivo**: Manipular 2 model na view utilizando uma ViewModel.

Fiz uma ViewModel para encapsular as 2 model, porém não consigo utilizar uma delas.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class BoletoConfigViewModel
{
    public Boleto Boletos { get; set; }
    public ConfigCliente Config { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    var config = db.Config
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClienteId == 3); //consulta com o DataBase
```

//Não tenho certeza que assim seria a melhor maneira dessa consulta.

```
    var viewModel = new BoletoConfigViewModel
    {
        Boletos = new Boleto(),
        Config = config
    };

    return View(viewModel);
```

**Na view:**

```
@model WMB.MVC.Extranet.ViewModel.BoletoConfigViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Boletos.DataVencimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Boletos.DataVencimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Boletos.DataVencimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

..//bastante codigo acima criado pelo Scanffolding...
Agora onde da problema
<div>Configuração.:</div> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Config.cur_Configuracao.ToString());
```

Mandaram eu fazer com uma partial view, etc... Porém para fins de aprendizado e imaginando que em outros lugares irei precisar isso não é possível?

***Erro:***

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions
Riga 85:     <div>Configuração.:</div> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Config.cur_Configuracao.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem é bastante clara:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Ou seja, você só pode usar `@Html.DisplayFor` com:

- Variáveis comuns da classe;
- Propriedades;
- Arrays com uma dimensão;
- Parâmetros com indexador de uma dimensão.

No caso, você usou `.ToString()`, que não é nenhum deles: é um método.

Há algumas opções que você pode usar:

### 1. A propriedade sem o `.ToString()`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Config.cur_Configuracao)
```

### 2. Retirar o `@Html.DisplayFor`:

```
@Model.Config.cur_Configuracao.ToString()
```

Comment: Mas se a propriedade (no meu caso decimal) posso mandar mostrar na tela ? Achei que só string podia mostrar na tela.

Comment: Pode sim. Não tem problema algum.