# Uma view utilizando dois models MVC

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho uma aplicação em MVC e preciso que uma view acesse dois models. Os models são:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E cada model tem seu controller, onde faço a conexão com o WebService para trazer os dados de outra aplicação.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que na view do Projeto eu consiga utilizar também o model DetalhePrjModel, como posso fazer isso? Sou novata em MVC então estou tendo bastante dificuldade para conseguir fazer isso...

Comment: Crie uma ViewModel que contenha suas duas models

Comment: Você pode usar as partial views.

Comment: Vamos com calma, primeiramente as actions são a mesma imagem. Segundo, não é possível chamar duas action, você vai precisar utilizar uma Partial View ou fazer uma camada de serviço.

Comment: Primeira coisa é postar o código em texto e remover as imagens.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110056/view-com-2-model-dentro-de-uma-viewmodel

Comment: Conceitualmente uma view deveria se vincular com uma única controller. Até é possível fazer mirabolismos como esse que você sugere, mas é um caminho sem volta, você começa a constriur problemas acima de você e vai ficando vez mais fundo. No fim sua aplicação tem dois caminhos funciona e nunca receberá manutenção (inviável) ou não funciona e seu trabalho terá sido inútil.

Answer (score 1):

É só criar uma `ViewModel` com as duas *models*

```
public class DetalheProjetoViewModel
{
    public ProjetoModel Projeto { get; set; }
    public DetalhePrjModel Detalhe { get; set; }
}
```

e depois trocar na *view*

```
@model DetalheProjetoViewModel
```

Comment: Criei a ViewModel

public class DetalheProjetoViewModel
{

    public DetalhePrjModel Detalhe { get; set; }
    public ProjetoModel Projeto { get; set; }

}
Troquei na view Projeto para model DetalheProjetoViewModel, só que quando vou fazer o for apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

IEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'Projeto' and no extension method 'Projeto' acceptin a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found
A view ficou assim:
foreach (var item in Model.Projeto) { 
Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Projeto.Codigo) }

Comment: @EmanueleBaron Se você precisa de uma lista na _view_ tem que mudar a declaração para `@model IEnumerable<DetalheProjetoViewModel>`